# How to calculate raster statistics for each values in a band?

Tags: qgis, rasterstats

I have one raster scene that contains one band with multiple pixel values (0-14).  Each values represent deforestation in certain year (0=no tree cover loss, 1=loss in 2001, 2=loss in 2002, and so on) and I need to calculate the deforestation statistics for each years (e.g. statistics for each pixel values in that scene).

I've tried using Zonal Statistics, but it only gives me a lump of all values (total count in zonal statistic = sum of all values). What I need is to count how many pixels have value '1', '2', and so on. Any suggestion on what tool(s) to use?
[image: Properties of the scene. It only has 1 band, and it contains value of 0-14 (0=no tree loss, 1=loss in year 2001, ..., 14=loss in year 2014)]

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to expand on what you currently get and what you actually want?  Add some examples or screenshots if it helps.

Comment: Clarified my question and added a screenshot of the scene properties. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Zonal Raster Statistics (also called Zonal Grid)](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/statistics_grid_5.html) tool to count the number of pixel in each class. The tool will create a new CSV file with the number of pixels for each category.

The only required parameter is the classified image `(Zonal Grid)` that contains the categories you want to calculate.

In the following example, I have a land use raster with 8 classes. When I run `Zonal Raster Statistics tool`, I got the following result:

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

The tool can be found from `Processing toolbox -> SAGA -> Geostatistics -> Zonal Raster Statistics`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the **SAGA Zonal Grid statistics**. This is available in Processing if you have SAGA GIS installed. I've not tried this yet but it looks like it will do what you want.

[According to the documentation](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/statistics_grid_5.html) this can create a contingency table (cross-tabulation) which includes the **number of pixels** ("n") in each category for each polygon.

The normal **zonal statistics** takes a polygon and raster layer as input.

However, this algorithm takes two (or more) raster layers instead. So you will need to convert your polygon layer to a raster layer (**using Raster > Conversion > Rasterize**) to use as your zonal grid, and your categorised raster as the categorical grid.

The output should be a table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what I'm doing with GIS but I wanted to achieve the same outcome as the OP. I'm on QGIS 3.16.0-Hannover and the existing answers didn't give me what I need (and they don't seem to live in the same spot in my version). I have a raster with a single band of values.

I found the `Raster layer unique values report` from the `Processing Toolbox` to be exactly what we're after. The description of this report is:

> This algorithm returns the count and area of each unique value in a given raster layer.

In the UI, you can find it here:
[image]

The output looks like:

```
Analyzed file: /vsigzip//tmp/south_australia_landcover.tif.gz (band 1)

Extent: 967587.0000000000000000,1315841.0000000000000000 : 1528884.0000000000000000,1962113.0000000000000000

Projection: GDA94 / SA Lambert

Width in pixels: 17009 (units per pixel 33)

Height in pixels: 19584 (units per pixel 33)

Total pixel count: 333104256

NODATA pixel count: 167256799

Value   Pixel count   Area (m²)
0       649033        706796937
110     11211         12208779
111     6832690       7440799410
112     1716817       1869613713
113     2899563       3157624107
114     811580        883810620
115     41014         44664246
116     374           407286
117     7973916       8683594524
...and so on
```