# How to extract land cover type data (%) from raster file using Zonal Stats from overlaid polygon grid, QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics, land-cover, feature-extraction

I have a very large raster file of land use types for a landscape. I am trying to run an occupancy model of large carnivores and need to test the weight as a covariate, of human settlements. Human settlements are marked red in the raster file band palette and the label reads 'human settlements'.

I've created a shapefile of a polygon grid of 6x6km cells. I need to know the % of each cell covered by human settlements.

I've ran Zonal Stats with the said polygon grid shp file (as 'vector layer containing zones') and the raster file but my resulting attribute table for the polygon shp file gives me no indication of %s (or any stats) of specific land types, just overall stats for the raster layer it seems.

How can I get data from my cells for specific land use types?

Comment: I've been following instructions here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242020/how-to-calculate-raster-statistics-for-each-values-in-a-band/242076. However I'm struggling to rasterize the polygon grid i'm using, and before I continue down that route would like to know if Zonal Stats can provide me the data I need

Comment: Without knowing the raster structure this is difficult to answer. Can you isolate just the required raster cells into a binary raster file to begin with?

Comment: I'm not sure what a binary raster file is. By isolating do you mean clipping? This is all new to me so apologies for more questions. I've managed to now rasterize the concerned polygon, but after running zonal grid I still do not have a clear breakdown of stats relevant to each value of the raster band within each cell of my grid.

Comment: What kind of raster is it? Is it a continuous or discrete raster (float or integer data)?  Does it have multiple bands, or a single band?  Unfortunately saying "Human settlements are marked red in the raster file band palette" does not let us know enough to understand your data.  Maybe Google a bit what discrete or continuous rasters are, and check if your is one or the other?

Comment: Incase more clarity is needed - I have a continuous raster with a single colourramp band. I also have an overlaid polygon grid, each cell labelled with an ID number. I need to  obtain for each cell of the grid a sum of each land cover type, or band label type, of the raster layer.

i.e. for Cell 1 I need to know the sum of or relative % of land covered in that particular cell by human settlement, closed woodland and bare land land types

Comment: Human settlements have a specific value in the raster? Can you add a screenshot of the symbology tab of the raster layer properties? I am thinking of extracting in a new raster only the human settlements and then apply zonal statistics of that raster for each cell / polygon of the vectorial grid.

Comment: If you could convert the raster to another that has values 1 for human settlements and values 0 for everything else, then the sum of all the pixel values in a cell, multiplied by the spatial resolution of the raster, gives the surface of human settlements in that cell, which multiplied by 100 and divided by the cell surface gives the occupation percentage.

Comment: Then, repeat the procedure for each type of coverage, in a separate column. The raster should be able to divide into as many raster as you have coverages. Maybe there is another way to play with the values of the pixels to determine all the percentages of occupation in a single sum, but I find it more difficult to implement. If you show us the properties of the raster layer, _Symbology_ tab and, if possible, complete _information_ tab, we can find the best way to do it.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca yes they have a specific value - apologies i don't appear able to attach screenshots. Its a colour ramped band and each land cover type as a value (0-29) and label (name - i.e. 'human settlement').This is a good suggestion, thanks, will try and revert back here.

Comment: @rae, hi. Save the screenshots as .png to upload. I was thinking about more practical ways (set in the raster the value of the surface of a pixel (or zero) and populate the cells with the zonal average) to obtain a coefficient of occupation. But all starts dividing the raster in.. do you have 30 categories? In one raster per category.